# Play framework form data bind issue

Tags: java, forms, data-binding, playframework-2.2

I am trying POST a form to a controller then bind data to a POJO object. Here is the POST data:

```
model  = M12345
//one or more hidden fileds with name 'images'
images = a.jpg
images = b.jpg
......
```

The POJO object look like below:

```
public class ProductForm {
   String model;
   String[] images;
}
```

Controller code:

```
ProductForm form = Form.form(ProductForm.class).bindFromRequest().get();
```

I am expecting that `form.images` contains all POST images value. eg`['a.jpg', 'b.jpg']`, but i got only one value`['a.jpg']`. I have tried to change the POST data to

```
model    = M12345
images[] = a.jpg
images[] = b.jpg
```

But i got an Exception:

```
InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'images[0]' of bean class [forms.product.ProductForm]: Invalid array index in property path 'images[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

How can i do? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try with a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]` for the `images` field ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. And same as `String[]`, only got 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is JSON then array should look like:

```
images: [
   a.jpg,
   b.jpg
]
```

Comment: Actually it's not JSON data, it's one or more hidden fileds with name 'images'.

Comment: Yes, i have tried 'images[0] = a.jpg \n images[1] = b.jpg' and got same exception with 'images[]'